# JSP returning null for request.getParameter() but shows values in EL

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, request, el

I am new to servlets and JSPs.
Recently.. I have been trying to send data from my Servlet to JSP using requestDispatcher.

This is my Servlet code responsible:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        sampleClass sampleObject = new sampleClass(1, "myname");
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        String jsonstring = mapper.writeValueAsString(sampleObject);
        request.setAttribute("values", jsonstring);
        request.setAttribute("valuees", "testing");
        request.getRequestDispatcher("/somejsp").forward(request, response);
    }
```

My JSP part responsible for retrieving data:

```
${values}
${valuees}
<% 
    //out.println(Message);
    Enumeration enume = request.getParameterNames();
    for (Entry<String, String[]> entry : request.getParameterMap().entrySet()) {
        String name = entry.getKey();
        String value = entry.getValue()[0];
        // ...
    }
    String value = request.getParameter("values");
    out.println(value);
    String valuee = request.getParameter("valuees");
    out.println(valuee);
 %>
```

But the output I get is:

{"n":1,"name":"myname"} testing null null

as you can see both the EL gives correct output, the implementation with the Enumeration returns nothing and the other two return null.

I donot understand this. I couldn't find any solution online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're confusing **attributes** (any object that you choose to store in the request, under a name you choose), with **parameters** (strings sent by the browser as part of the request, as in `foo=bar&baz=2`.